# Error handling using Flowable.generate RxJava

Tags: java, apache-kafka, rx-java, kafka-consumer-api, reactive-streams

I am building a Kafka consumer `Flowable` using `Flowable.generate` and here is my implementation

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

public class RxKafkaUtils {

  /**
   * Returns a flowable impl for a Kafka Consumer
   */
  public static @NonNull Flowable < Object > source(Properties props, String[] topics) {
    final
    var consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
    return Flowable.generate(
      () -> {
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topics));
        return ConsumerRecords.empty().iterator();
      },
      (state, emitter) -> {
        if (state.hasNext()) {
          emitter.onNext(state.next());
          return state;
        } else {
          try {
            return consumer.poll(1000).iterator();
          } catch (Throwable t) {
            consumer.close();
            emitter.onError(t);
            throw t;           // <------ HERE
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Since `KafkaConsumer` can throw Exceptions, I've wrapped the `.poll` in a try-catch.

My doubt is, should I rethrow the `Throwable`? If not, the compiler asks for a return value from the catch block and in this case, I don't really have any

What's the right way to implement this (in other words – graceful shutdown)?

Is `Flowable.generate` even the right thing for this? I tried using `Flowable.fromPublisher` but the state management was a total mess, or I was doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out,

`Flowable.generate` accepts a `disposeState` Consumer which gets called after `onComplete/onError`. The current state (or the final state I return gets passed to the `disposeState` consumer)